# Почему результат TO_TIMSTAMP отличается от TO_CHAR при одной и той же маске для парсинга?

Tags: sql, oracle

При получении текущей даты/времени запросом:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

результат корректный

> 28-10-2019 08:33:50

Но если пытаюсь получить так:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

> 28-10-2019 08:33:50

<sub>Прим.ред.: здесь по видимому имеет место ошибка при копировании результата.</sub>

Comment: Вообще to_timestamp конвертирует строку в timestamp, а вы ему sysdate передаете, который сначала дефолным методом конвертится в строку, а потом эта строка отдается to_timestamp и она не в том формате, который вы указываете. поэтому результат непредсказуем. Кроме того когда oracle вернет результат в виде timestamp ваше средство вывода на экран само может применить любой формат для вывода (так как возвращена не строка)

Comment: @Mike А можете подсказать, как тогда записать в столбец текущее время при выполнении INSERT новой строки?

Comment: Systimestamp вернёт текущее время в формате timestamp

Comment: _Но если пытаюсь получить ..._ - в резултате вы показали то же  самое значение 28-10-2019 08:33:50. А в чём смысл вашего вопроса?

Comment: @Roberto А столбец какого типа ? если date/datetime/timestamp то прямо SYSDATE и вставляйте, ничего не конвертируя. Или используйте для типа timestamp, как предложили в ответах, `systemtimestamp`

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка здесь: `TO_TIMESTAMP (SYSDATE, ....)`. Нет перегруженной функции `TO_TIMESTAMP` для типа даных `DATE`.  То есть, сначало `SYSDATE` будет **неявно** преобразован в символьное значение в соответствии с форматом по умолчанию, который можно узнать так:

```
show parameters nls_date_format
```

Посмотрите, какой совсем неожиданный результат это может дать:

```sql
alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/rr hh:mi:ss';

select to_timestamp (sysdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "Сейчас" from dual;

Сейчас
-----------------------------
0020-08-06 11:12:27,000000000
```

Но сегодня не 20-й год от Р. Х. и вовсе не август.